# jQuery Malsup Submit Checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am trying to submit a form with the malsup form plugin through a checkbox, but i am not able to do so i found something similar that said to do the following, but i cannot pass the option. Has anyone done something similar to this?

```
  //Check SMS Credits
    var checksmscredits = { 
    target:     '#responsecredits', 
    beforeSubmit:  showRequest, 
    url:        'exec.php?action=checksmscredits',
    success:    function() { 
       jQuery('.loaders').hide();
       } 
   }; 

   jQuery('#checksmscredits').ajaxForm(checksmscredits);

<form id="checksmscredits" method="post" action=""><p><span class="pagedesc"><input type="checkbox" name="sms" onclick="submit()" value="1" /> Text Your Message<br /></span></p></form><div id="responsecredits"></div>
```

This is what i found online in the following link
[submit form using ajaxform on checkbox click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964678/submit-form-using-ajaxform-on-checkbox-click)

```
$('form.date-response input[type=checkbox]').live('click', function(){
    $(this).parent('form').ajaxForm().submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With the code snippet provided, here's a suggestion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var options = { 
                data: $('#checksmscredits').serialize(),
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    showSuccess();
                },
                error: function()
                {
                    showError();
                }
            }; 
            $('#checksmscredits').ajaxForm(options); 
    });

    function showSuccess(){
        alert('Success!');
    }

    function showError(){
        alert('Error!');
    }
</script>

<form id="checksmscredits" method="post" action="">
    <p><span class="pagedesc">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sms" onclick="document.getElementById('checksmscredits').submit();" value="1" /> 
        Text Your Message<br />
    </span></p>
</form>
<div id="responsecredits"></div>
```